# Implementing Bootstrap DatePicker3 in mvc 4 project Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Im currently trying to implement a datepicker control which has both date and time modficiation. The Package i found was [this](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

When i run the create view i get the following error:

Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'

Any ideas as to how to solve this problem, I have tried some of the methods proposed in the other instance of this problem but no luck.

```
@model IndustryProject1._3.Models.Appointment

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Appointment</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Start, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Start, new { @class = "form-control datepicker " })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Start, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div> 

//rest of razor form

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Start').datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
        });
    });

</script>
```

Bundles Config

```
public class BundleConfig
    {

        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));


            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/moment").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/moment.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
          "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
            //css  
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/cssjqryUi").Include(
                   "~/Content/jquery-ui.css"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which element are you assigning the datePicker to? Is `#` even valid?

Comment: `$('#')` is not referring to an element in your view it needs to be `$('#Start')` and you using `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js`, so its `$('#Start').datetimepicker() { ... }`

Comment: Sorry guys thats a misprint even with #Start included the same error appears

Comment: @whiskeycoder Make sure that `Start` is referencing the `TextBoxFor` helper and not the `LabelFor` in the html markup. I can't remember if the Model Binder will just make both id elements `Start` and then jquery just chooses the first one but this might be happening.

Comment: to test the idea i removed the label for and no chage is there a better way to test if its still refencing the labelfor

Comment: @whiskeycoder, The label has nothing to do with it. See my first comment (`.datetimepicker()`, not `.datepicker()`)

Comment: I think that was it im getting a new error but that solved the error i was having. Thanks @StephenMuecke  for the help

Comment: It a bit strange that you have shown all you bundles, but have not used them in the view at all - and if you have then why have you added the script tags manually as well?

Comment: I added the bundles just from looking at other questions posed by users many of them asked to see the bundles and ive been trying some solutions to the problem for the last few hours so i have a bit of tidying up to do now